# Datepicker can be triggered outside of visual box

Tags: convertigo

I got some issues with the Datetime component :

1. Whenever I click on a place above or below the component, it will trigger the datetime and hide my text areas. I tried to fix it by doing some styling in the css but I couldn't find out a solution.
2. I would like to put the current date as a placeholder for my datetime component so I declared a myDate variable in the .ts which provides the date and bound it to the placeholder property. Looks like it works but when I want to change the date, the time doesn't update. 
   **Edit : The time is now updating after a complete reload, but the time variable I declared at the right place in the .ts in between the comments is deleted when I reload the project**

Related question : I was looking for a list picker in the mobile palette but didn't find one. Ionic provides an ion-picker, do I have to create a new fragment that calls such component ?

Thanks in advance,
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you put the **DateTime** component in an **ion-item** as recommended in Ionic framework v3 ?

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

2. Do not directly edit the .TS files, they are automatically generated each time you modify the **Application**. To add local variables or functions to a Page, right-click on it and choose **Edit page class**. Add your code after /*Begin_c8o_XXX*/ comments:

```
/*Begin_c8o_PageDeclaration*/
public myDate = new Date();
/*End_c8o_PageDeclaration*/
```

Set **this.myDate** in TS mode in the **Placeholder** property of the DateTime component.  Format Date to your need. Picking a new date and time should update value of the component. Check **Display format** and **Picker format** properties.

3. **ion-picker** is a V4 Ionic component and is not yet supported in Convertigo.